# Python - chatbot A.I are there any that use nltk?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, nltk

I am attempting to make a chat A.I, I curious if anyone used nltk, and could point me in the direction on how it can be used to generate a response based on the information nltk gathers, and how would you store the nltk information gathered? I've been doing research on this but came up empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few resources to get you started:

1. The [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) which has a lot of excellent examples that would be relevant to you.
2. The [nltk.chat](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chat.html) package described as

> This chatbot is a tongue-in-cheek take on the average teen anime junky that frequents YahooMessenger or MSNM. All spelling mistakes and flawed grammar are intentional.

...and perhaps companion read: [Be your own bot master](http://www.alicebot.org/be.html) site and book by Dr. Richard Wallace.

3. A [Gamasutra tutorial](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6305/beyond_fa%C3%A7ade_pattern_matching_.php)
4. A [real world project example](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/projects/bonniejc.pdf)
5. Some [real world code example](https://github.com/chatbotimporved/chatbot)